# ActionController::Parameters to_query fails after upgrading to Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

In Rails 4.2.4, `ActionController::Parameters.new(pos: 'xyz', foo: 'bar').to_query` returns `"foo=bar&pos=xyz"`.

After upgrading to Rails 5.0, I get this:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
from /Users/Lars/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.rc2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_query.rb:11:in `to_query'
from (irb):7
from /Users/Lars/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
from /Users/Lars/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/Lars/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `console'
from /Users/Lars/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
from /Users/Lars/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.rc2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

But the documentation for `to_query` clearly says the parameter for to_query is (still) optional: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_query

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the documentation for Rails 5.1.1, the documentation for 5.0.0 can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0/).

In 5.0.0.rc2, the #to_query method is coming from [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.rc2/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_query.rb#L11-L13), indeed requiring an argument (key).

This changed between versions, it doesn't require an argument since Rails 5.0.3. I'd suggest simply updating your Rails version. If that's not an option, this might work for you:

```
Rack::Utils.build_query(ActionController::Parameters.new(pos: 'xyz', foo: 'bar')) # => "pos=xyz&foo=bar"
```

Comment: I _did_ spend 5 minutes trying to find the 5.0 documentation without success, and then I decided that it was too unlikely that `to_query` required an argument just for one version.

Once I get 5.0 working I'll upgrade to 5.1, so I'll just leave this unresolved until then.

Comment: @LarsP what was the proper solution you found for this?

Comment: I probably just upgraded to 5.1.